# Why is my "import msvcrt" statement not working?

Tags: python, msvcrt

I am writing this code in python (on my windows 10 machine) :

```
import msvcrt

a = getch()
```

and I'm getting this error when I try to run it using python3:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Simon.py", line 2, in <module>
    import msvcrt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'
[Exit 1 ]
```

Anyone know how I can make this import work? The functionality of the `getch()` method is the last thing I need for this program to work.

Comment: `msvcrt` is a module in the standard library, so if Python is installed correctly, it should be available.

Comment: Off-topic: When you get the `import` problem resolved, you will need to call `msvcrt.getch()` to use the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely trying this in an environment that runs on Linux. `msvcrt` is part of the standard Python libraries for Windows, but not available on Linux.

If you only need it on Windows:

```
from platform import system
if system() == 'Windows':
    from msvcrt import getch
```

If you need it on both Windows and Linux, you may want to install the third party `getch` library. For example, on my CentOS VM that would would be:

```
sudo yum install gcc
sudo yum install python3-devel
pip install getch
```

After that, you can update your code to:

```
from platform import system
if system() == 'Windows':
    from msvcrt import getch
else:
    from getch import getch
```

Alternatively, make clear what you need `getch()` for and look for an alternative that doesn't depend on platform-specific imports.